# Error with trying to find Min&max when also finding average of "n" number of user inputs

Tags: java, loops, average, minmax

```
package HW2_Min_Max;

import java.util.Scanner; 

public class HW2_Min_Max {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input a positive interger that indicates number of positive intergers ");

        int number = myScanner.nextInt();

        while (number <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please input interger");
            number = myScanner.nextInt();
        }

        int i=1; //i is to store current iteration
        int sum=0; //sum is to store sum of the input 
        int x; //x is to store the user input

        while (i <= number){
            System.out.println("Please input a positive interger ");
            x = myScanner.nextInt();
            sum = sum + x;
            i++;
        }
        int average = sum/number;

        System.out.println("The average is " + average);

        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        if (number < min){
            min = number;
        }

        if (number > max) {
            max = number;
        }
        System.out.println("The minimum value is " + min);
        System.out.print( "and the maximum value is" + max);
        }
    }
}
```

1.^ this is where i am getting my problem, on the very last brace in Netbeans i am getting an error that says "class, interface, or enum expected" but i have no idea why. Excuse my ignorance as I am a very fresh beginner with java, let alone programming.

Comment: It appears the last brace is not required at all actually. Remember that the number of `{` should be equal to the number of `}`, you want to ensure every brace you open is closed eventually.

Comment: Proper, consistent indentation is your friend.

Comment: Okay so that fixed the problem of letting me run the code, but i'm getting a problem with my actual output? I input 5 positive integers, the average always comes out right, but the outputs for the max and min come out wrong, i don't know why?

Comment: Don't redefine your question in the comments. If you have another question, ask it separately. And include a lot more detail.

Comment: Not really directly to your question, but the word "interger" is properly "integer", as in [`java.lang.Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

Comment: @F.ochoa15, Kindly check my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, I would suggest you use a `do-while` loop to test for the number of numbers. Like,

```
int number;
do {
    System.out.println("Please input a positive integer that "
            + "indicates number of positive integers ");
    number = myScanner.nextInt();
} while (number <= 0);
```

Then you need to set `min` and `max` *in* your loop (or store all the values you read). I would prefer `Math.max` and `Math.min`. I would also count from `0`. Like,

```
int i = 0; // i is to store current iteration
int sum = 0; // sum is to store sum of the input
int x; // x is to store the user input
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // store the max user input
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // store the min user input
while (i < number) {
    System.out.println("Please input a positive integer ");
    x = myScanner.nextInt();
    if (x > 0) { // make sure it's a positive integer
        min = Math.min(min, x);
        max = Math.max(max, x);
        sum += x;
        i++;
    }
}
int average = sum / number;
System.out.println("The average is " + average);
System.out.println("The minimum value is " + min);
System.out.println("and the maximum value is " + max);
```

Answer (score -1):

Its working fine now. I have made some changes in it. Kindly consider it. I hope it would help.

```
 Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please input a positive interger that indicates number of positive intergers ");


     int number = myScanner.nextInt();

    while (number <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Please input interger");
        number = myScanner.nextInt();
    }
    int[] arr = new int[number]; // Store values in array
    int i=0; //i is to store current iteration
    int sum=0; //sum is to store sum of the input
    int x; //x is to store the user input
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
       for(i=0;i<number;i++){
        System.out.println("Please input a positive interger ");
        arr[i] = myScanner.nextInt();
        sum = sum + arr[i];

    }
    int average = sum/number;

    System.out.println("The average is " + average);

    // Put initial values in min and max for comparing
    min =arr[0];
     max = arr[0];
for(i=1;i<number;i++)
{
    // Compare if values is less than arr[i]
    if (arr[i] < min){
        min = arr[i];
    }
// Compare if values is greater than arr[i]
    if (arr[i] > max) {
        max = arr[i];
    }
}
    System.out.print("The minimum value is " + min);
    System.out.println( " and the maximum value is " + max);

}
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]